# how to add controls dynamically to table layout panel from panel

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I have placed all the controls in one panel.During the run time i would like to add the control to table layout panel. To do that i have written following code.

```
 void arrangeTableLayout()
    {
        int rowcount = 1;           
            tblPanel.ColumnCount=2;           
            tblPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            tblPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            for (int i = 0; i < panel.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                if (panel.Controls[i].Visible)
                {

                  tblPanel.Controls.Add(panel.Controls[i], 0, rowcount);
                  tblPanel.Controls.Add(panel.Controls[i + 1], 1, rowcount);
                  tblPanel.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 40F));                            
                   i++;                           
                   rowcount++;
                 }                    
            }            
    }
```

in the control array the controls are there as required to me. But the above code adding only labels in one column.

Can any one tell me how to add the windows form controls dynamically to the table layout panel.

Comment: You are moving a control from panel to tblPanel.  Which modifies the panel.Controls collection.  So panel.Controls[i+1] is not what you think it is, it is the *second* control after panel.Controls[i].

Comment: yes. if i check the name of that control panel.Controls[i+1].Name the proper name only coming for me. But it is not adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its worked for me.

```
 void arrangeTableLayout()
 {
    int rowcount = 1;           
        tblPanel.ColumnCount=2;           
        tblPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        tblPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
        for (int i = 0; i < panel.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (panel.Controls[i].Visible)
            {
             var c1 = panel.Controls[i];
             var c2 = GetNextControl(panel.Controls[i], true);
             panel.Controls.Remove(c1);
             i--;                            
             panel.Controls.Remove(c2);
             tblPanel.Controls.Add(c1, 0, rowcount);
             tblPanel.Controls.Add(c2, 1, rowcount);
             tblPanel.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 40F));                                          
             rowcount++;
             }                    
        }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to do that.

```
   tblPanel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Type:", Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left, AutoSize = true }, 0, 0);
   tblPanel.Controls.Add(new ComboBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, 0, 1);
```

you don't need to define number of rows and columns, they will be added automatically.

Combobox use as a example. Replace it with your controls

Comment: i don't want to add dynamically generated labels. the labels and textbox controls are there in my design. based on some condition it will change the visibility. So i have to rearrange the  existing controls only.

Comment: yes same thing i am doing in  tblPanel.Controls.Add(panel.Controls[i], 0, rowcount);

Comment: if i am not adding   tblPanel.ColumnCount=2;     line then only one column is coming.